# Applying custom color to jquery ui-icons

Tags: jquery-ui

I am new to jQuery. I want to use the "ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e" with a color that matches my application ,also I dont want use a differnt .png file with the color I want. Please help me get this done.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option *is* to use a different PNG file, that's the only option for this really (that works cross-browser).  However it's pretty easy to get the color you want, use the [jQuery UI ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) and you can configure/download the exact colors you want in a theme, including the icons.